# Ошибка: missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, tkinter

Как исправить эту ошибку? Искал решения в интернете - там как-то всё странно и не то что мне нужно :(
Ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: dobavka() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'message' and 
'films'
```

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def dobavka(message, films):    
    films.append(message.get())
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', 'Добавлен фильм: '+message.get())

def otbavka(message, films):
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', 'Вы добавили фильм '+message.get()+' в список просмотренных')
    f = open('Фильм с follentass.txt', 'w+')
    f.write(''+message.get()+' ')
    films.remove(message.get())
    f.close()

root = Tk()
root.title('Фильмы с follentass')
root.geometry('800x300')

message = StringVar()

message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message,width=52)
message_entry.place(relx=.3, rely=.1, anchor='c')

message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить',width=30, command=dobavka)
message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.1, anchor='c')

films = ['Выберите просмотренный фильм из списка ниже',
       'Kingsman: Секретная служба',
       'Синяя бездна',
       'Притворись моей женой',
       'Тупой и еще тупее 2',
       'Тупой и еще тупее',
       'И грянул шторм',
       'Папа-досвидос',
       'Мачо и ботан'] 

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(films[0]) 

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *films)
w.place(relx=.3, rely=.3, anchor='c')

message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить в просмотренные',width=30, command=otbavka)
message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.3, anchor='c')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить', width=30, command=dobavka)
```

Вы делаете кнопку, по клику на которую выполнится функция `dobavka`. Но аргументы Вы в неё не передаёте, а ведь сигнатура `dobavka` такова, что ей нужно два входных параметра. И передать аргументы в эту функцию можно двумя способами:

Первый - с использованием модуля [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import partial
message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить', width=30,
    command=partial(dobavka, message, films))
```

Второй - с использованием лямбда-функций:

```
message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить',width=30,
    command=lambda: dobavka(message, films))
```

С функцией `otbavka` есть аналогичная проблема, которую такими же способами можно решить.

Answer (score 0):

### Гораздо проще:

Вам не следует передавать аргументы в эти функции 
т.к вы используете уже создание переменные.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def add():

    films.append(message.get())
    print(films)
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', 'Добавлен фильм: '+message.get())
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set(films[0]) 
    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *films)
    w.place(relx=.3, rely=.3, anchor='c')
def delete():
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', 'Вы добавили фильм '+message.get()+' в список просмотренных')
    print("It is "+message.get())
    f = open('Фильм с follentass.txt', 'w+')
    f.write(''+message.get()+' ')
    try:
        films.remove(message.get())
    except:
        pass
    f.close()
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set(films[0]) 
    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *films)
    w.place(relx=.3, rely=.3, anchor='c')

root = Tk()
root.title('Фильмы с follentass')
root.geometry('800x300')
message = StringVar()

message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message,width=52)
message_entry.place(relx=.3, rely=.1, anchor='c')

message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить',width=30, command=add)
message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.1, anchor='c')

films = ['Выберите просмотренный фильм из списка ниже',
       'Kingsman: Секретная служба',
       'Синяя бездна',
       'Притворись моей женой',
       'Тупой и еще тупее 2',
       'Тупой и еще тупее',
       'И грянул шторм',
       'Папа-досвидос',
       'Мачо и ботан'] 

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(films[0]) 

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *films)
w.place(relx=.3, rely=.3, anchor='c')

message_button = ttk.Button(text='Добавить в просмотренные',width=30, command=delete)
message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.3, anchor='c')

root.mainloop()
```